# value not binding with array object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an app that deals with ordering coffee. The coffee store has a table that shows drink types by size, and they can click on a given drink/size and edit data about that drink/size combo, such as the price.

Before, there was a set list of coffee drinks (mocha, cappuccino, etc) and I was able to *gasp* hardcode the drinks and get by this bug. However, things have changed and now the store can add custom drinks, meaning that I can no longer hardcode the drinks and I need to get the store drinks from the API.

This project is using Ember 1.13, and I'm setting the drinks in the `setupController` in the route. In this example I'm not going to be showing the custom drinks, the problem is reproducible just by using the default drinks.

```
model: function() {
    let myStoreId = this.controllerFor('application').get('myStore.id');

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      myStore: this.store.find('store', myStoreId),
      storeDrinks: this.store.find('store-drink', {'store':myStoreId}),
      ...
    });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {

    // we have some set drinks that will be for every store, although they can set inactive
    let defaultDrinks = [
      "Americano", "Capuccino", "Drip", "Espresso", "Latte", "Mocha", "Tea"
    ];
    let drinksArray = [];
    let drinkType, keyName;

    let pluralize = function(string){
      // return plural and lower case for a drink type
      let lower = string.toLowerCase();
      let plural = lower + "s";
      return plural;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < defaultDrinks.length; i++) {
      drinkType = defaultDrinks[i];
      keyName = pluralize(drinkType);

      // when we define like this, there are bugs editing in the template. But we 
      // can loop though all the drinks by type. I can get a list of custom drinks
      // from the API and add those into the loop.

      drinksArray[keyName] = this.store.filter('store-drink', function(drink) {
        return drink.get('type') === drinkType;
      });
    }

    // when we define like this (hardcode), it works fine in template but we
    // can't keep doing this because with custom drinks we don't know the type
    // when we get the above loop working, this code will be gone, but it shows
    // what works in the template to edit drinks.

    let cappuccinos = this.store.filter('store-drink', function(drink) {
      return drink.get('type') === "Cappuccino";
    });

    ...

    console.log(drinksArray["mochas"], cappuccinos);

    controller.setProperties({
      'mochas': drinksArray["mochas"],
      'cappuccinos': cappuccinos,
      ...

      'myStore': model.myStore,
    });
}
```

There's the setup in the route. Now in the template I have an input that is tied to the drink value. When they click on one of the drink/size combos, it opens a div that has the `detailDrink` object. `{{input value=detailDrink.price ... }}`.

When the drink uses the drinkList in the form of `cappuccino` everything works fine. When the drink uses the drinkList in the form of `drinksArray["mochas"]` then when the input changes, there are various bugs. I don't believe the details of this part to be significant but sometimes it deletes the cell value, sometimes it doesn't reflect the change, and sometimes it binds multiple cells to the same value. **The issue is that when using the data from an array (such as with mochas) this bug is there, and when using the hardcoded value (such as with cappuccinos) the drink data can be updated correctly.**

Another thing to note is that in the `console.log(drinksArray["mochas"], cappuccinos);` above, both objects appear to be the same, other than of course one is a list of cappuccinos and the other is a list of mochas.

I've literally been stuck on this for months off-and-on, and have tried so many things and have isolated it down to this.

**EDIT ADDITION:**
You might think "how will this help your problem"? My idea is to have an array of objects such as:

```
[{
  'drinkSet': cappuccinos,
  'drinkType': 'Cappuccino',
}, {
  'drinkSet': mochas,
  'drinkType': 'Mocha',  
},
{
  'drinkSet': myCustomWhiteChocolateThunder,
  'drinkType': 'White Chocolate Thunder',  
},
...
]
```

and then loop through my template table rows with each drink type

```
    <table class="table table-striped menu__drink-table hidden-xs">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Drink</th>
          <th>8oz</th>
          <th>12oz</th>
          <th>16oz</th>
          <th>20oz</th>
          <th>24oz</th>
          <th>32oz</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each drinkSetObject in drinkSets}}
          {{joe-menu-row drinkSet=drinkSetObject.drinkSet type=drinkSetObject.drinkType detailDrink=detailDrink}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I had this before, but isolated the problem down to the fact that when the drinks were a value in an array for some reason they don't work as they do when declaring the variable directly.

Comment: any suggestions to improve the question are much appreciated as well, this will likely go to bounty...

Comment: ok will wait for bounty ;) , nah kidding, working on a twiddle so we can re-produce this for you, just a sec

Comment: @TameBadger thanks. I spent a good 2 hours this morning trying to reproduce the problem in ember twiddle but had no luck :/

Comment: Check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/aa1dcf74c9ee4add641abe1d0c07b0da?) out please, and see if you can try to migrate some of your code to match mine ?

Comment: A few things to "fix" in the code, you can use the ember inflector to pluralize names, make a component to deal with the drinks instead of doing it in `setupController`, find me on slack I ll guide you through it

Comment: @TameBadger Thanks so much for your time setting that up & help, sorry I could not reproduce. Turns out the promises don't resolve in setupController when in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem resolving promises in setup controller. Seems that promise in an array does not resolve so you can't get the data in the template.

Please try the next and let me know:

```
for (let i = 0; i < defaultDrinks.length; i++) {
    // can't be method variables since will be used in the promise
    let drinkType = defaultDrinks[i];
    let keyName = pluralize(drinkType);

    this.store.filter('store-drink', function(drink) {
        return drink.get('type') === drinkType;
    }).then(function(result) {
        controller.set(keyName, result);
    }, function(error) {
        //TODO: handle error
    });
}
```

Also, use the ember inflector's [pluralize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Inflector.html#method_pluralize) function:

```
const { Inflector: { inflector } } = Ember
let keyName = inflector.pluralize(drinkType);
```

Hope it helps

ps: dont forget to remove the controller.setProperties setup

Comment: Protip: use `.forEach` on defaultDrinks since it's an array.

Comment: @Kitler thanks for pluralize edition. I just copied from an old project.